# Generating dockerfile of a gradle java application

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, gradle, docker

This is my build.gradle file. In eclipse, I run docker task via gradle in eclipse, there is no error and it generates dockerfile and image. But when I try to write `gradle build` in ubuntu terminal at project location, I get an error. I will try to run task to get dockerfile of project later by writing `gradle distDucker`.

> build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
 dependencies {
  classpath "se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2"
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'docker'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

mainClassName = 'kafka.MyProducer'

applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ['-Xmx1g',
                         '-Xms1g']

dependencies {
compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.11',version: '0.10.0.0'    
 }

task copyConf(type: Copy) {
from System.getProperty('user.dir') + "/conf"
into "$buildDir/conf"
}

task createConf {
def conf = file("$buildDir/conf")
outputs.dir conf
doLast {
    conf.mkdirs()
    copyConf.execute()
}
}

distributions {
main {
    contents {
        from(createConf) { into "/conf" }
    }
}
}

docker {
baseImage = 'brscrt/java-8'
maintainer = 'Baris Cirit "brscrt@gmail.com"'
}

distDocker {
tag = 'brscrt/kafkaproducer'
  version = 'latest'

push = project.hasProperty('push') ? project.property('push') : false
} 


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { gradleVersion = '2.14' }
```

> This error on terminal:

```
baris@brscrt:~/workspace/KafkaProducer_Gr$ gradle build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/baris/workspace/KafkaProducer_Gr/build.gradle' line: 12

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'KafkaProducer_Gr'.
    > Could not create task of type 'DockerTask'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.9 secs
```

> Stacktrace is complicated. After typed `gradle build --stacktrace` :

```
baris@brscrt:~/workspace/KafkaProducer_Gr$ gradle build --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/baris/workspace/KafkaProducer_Gr/build.gradle' line: 12

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'KafkaProducer_Gr'.
 > Could not create task of type 'DockerTask'.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'KafkaProducer_Gr'.
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:127)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildScriptProcessor.evaluate(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
at org.gradle.configuration.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:466)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:77)
at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:23)
at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:21)
at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$CompositeAction.execute(Actions.java:78)
at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$TransformingActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:130)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.configure(AbstractProject.java:442)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.allprojects(AbstractProject.java:437)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:40)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:38)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:39)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:25)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskInstantiationException: Could not create task of type 'DockerTask'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskFactory$1.call(TaskFactory.java:115)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskFactory$1.call(TaskFactory.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.injectIntoNewInstance(AbstractTask.java:138)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskFactory.createTaskObject(TaskFactory.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskFactory.createTask(TaskFactory.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.createTask(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:93)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DependencyAutoWireTaskFactory.createTask(DependencyAutoWireTaskFactory.java:39)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.add(DefaultTaskContainer.java:53)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.task(AbstractProject.java:929)
at org.gradle.api.Project$task.call(Unknown Source)
at se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.DockerPlugin.addDistDockerTask(DockerPlugin.groovy:48)
at se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.DockerPlugin.this$2$addDistDockerTask(DockerPlugin.groovy)
at se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.DockerPlugin$_apply_closure1.doCall(DockerPlugin.groovy:42)
at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$FilteredAction.execute(Actions.java:203)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:115)
at org.gradle.api.DomainObjectCollection$all.call(Unknown Source)
at se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.DockerPlugin.apply(DockerPlugin.groovy:41)
at se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.DockerPlugin.apply(DockerPlugin.groovy)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.providePlugin(DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.java:107)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.addPluginInternal(DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.java:71)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.apply(DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.java:37)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyPlugin(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:101)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:32)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:72)
at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:114)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.apply(AbstractProject.java:854)
at org.gradle.api.Project$apply.call(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:34)
at org.gradle.api.Script$apply.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at build_6evdo45vm72o57c2gvqaus0hpp.run(/home/baris/workspace/KafkaProducer_Gr/build.gradle:12)
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling
at se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.DockerTask.<init>(DockerTask.groovy:104)
at se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.DockerTask_Decorated.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.newInstance(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.newInstance(ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskFactory$1.call(TaskFactory.java:113)
... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.ShortTypeHandling
... 69 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.897 secs
```

> Line 12 in build.gradle : `apply plugin: 'docker'`

Comment: Can you run the same `gradle build` with `--stacktrace` option please?

Comment: I added `--stacktrace` message to question. I think gradle doesn't see `docker plugin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using older version of gradle/groovy, because `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.ShortTypeHandling` was introduced in groovy `2.3` and according to the stack trace the class loader cannot find it while trying to apply `docker` plugin.

Comment: Thanks gusto. My local groovy and gradle groovy versions were different. I reinstalled gradle via sdkman. And problem is gone.